# IntelliJ: Big cursor on darcula theme

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

Editor section don't show anything except enormous cursor. This also occurs in other sections where you write text e.g. console / event logs.

Bug doesn't occur in default theme. 
I find workaround: if I create new editor scheme, based on Dracula and put it in default theme, it works normal.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwomC.png
(Editor should be full of text)

I use Linux Mint & Cinnamon.

Comment: I'd ask Jetbrains support directly if I were you, after reinstalling and resetting options.

Comment: Right click on editor and uncheck the "Column Selection Mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Debian with Mate and have same issue.
I couldn't resolve this issue with darcula theme, but I found way to resolve it with custom theme.

```
1. Settins->Editor->Colors & Fonts
2. Select darcula theme
3. Save as "custom" e.g.
4. Select font that you want to use.
```

That's it. It works ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the next person who accidentally activates this with a keyboard shortcut:

This is **not** related to Linux, theme or font. It is a new feature described in the [release notes](http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2014/03/whats-mining-multiple-cursors-and-selection/) of march 2014. It makes it possible for the caret/cursor to expand over multiple lines for multiline editing.

To turn it on/off: go to Edit > Column Selection Mode
You can also permanently remove the keyboard shortcut in Preferences > Keymap.